# How to give id and name for dynamically created editable html table each cells with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When clicking the button it will call the function `GenerateTable()` and create a table dynamically based on the multiple options selected in the drop-down as table column heading. below is my javascript code, then how to give id and name for each text field in the cells?
Also, I have one button is there in the dynamically created table for adding new rows, below is the function to add and delete rows.
Here is my Code

```js
function GenerateTable() {
     var selected = [];
     var rows=[];

     selected.push("S.No");
     selected.push("Drawing No");

     rows.push("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
     rows.push("<input type=text size=3>");

        $.each($(".chosen-select option:selected"), function(){ 
            selected.push($(this).val());
            rows.push("<input type=text size=3>");
        });
     selected.push("<a id='addMore2' onClick='addRow();'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a>"); 
     rows.push("<a class='remove_row'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>");

    //Create a HTML Table element.
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.setAttribute('id', 'generated_table');
    table.setAttribute('class', 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover');

    //Get the count of columns.
    var columnCount = selected.length;
    //Add the header row.
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
        headerCell.innerHTML = selected[i];
        row.appendChild(headerCell);
    }

    //Add the data rows.
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var rowCell = document.createElement("td");
        rowCell.innerHTML = rows[i];
        row.appendChild(rowCell);   
    }

    var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
    dvTable.innerHTML = "";
    dvTable.appendChild(table);
}
function addRow() {
            var data = $("#generated_table tr:eq(1)").clone(true);
            $('#generated_table tr:last').before(data);
}

$(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function() {
            var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();

                if(trIndex>1) {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            } else {

            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="GenerateTable()" value="Add" id="add">                           
    <select multiple class="chosen-select" name="multi_drop" id="multi_drop">
                                   <option value="A">A</option>
                                   <option value="B">B</option>
                                   <option value="C">C</option>
                                   <option value="D">D</option>
                                   <option value="E">E</option>
        </select>
<div id="dvTable"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you pasting `<html>` tags everywhere? `<html><input type=text size=3></html>` It doesn't make sense.

Comment: because i want to type values in that to save

Comment: @shaheem There's no point in using multiple <html> tags in one file. Use it only once - as a container for all other tags

Comment: @Ryan sorry my mistake, i removed html tag. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use "setAttribute" method to add and edit attributes (including id and name), [take a look at this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I cheked what you provided, but there is no tag name id name and name in created cells then how to use getElements there?  Sorry i am beginner.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery to loop through all the table cells

```
$('table tr td').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr('id', index); //the id must be unique!
    $(this).attr('name', 'whateveryouwant');
});
```

This is the basic.

You can modify the selector to reach inner elements:

```
$('table tr td a').each(function( index ) {
    $(this).attr('id', index); //the id must be unique!
    $(this).attr('name', 'whateveryouwant');
});
```

if you want to add the ids and other attributes when you create the element, modify your code:

```
//Add the data rows.
row = table.insertRow(-1);
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var rowCell = document.createElement("td");
    rowCell.innerHTML = rows[i];

    rowCell.setAttribute("id", someUniqueId);
    rowCell.setAttribute("class", someClassName);

    row.appendChild(rowCell);   
}
```

Remeber that the id of elements must be unique in the whole document, so you have to keep track of the used IDs